# My search code is not outputting any result on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, search, model-view-controller

Please help!!

I am trying to search database to produce results for my search query but it does not output any result even when the searched term exist in the database

Here is my controller

```
<?php 
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class Search extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("profile_model");
        $this->load->model("model_home");
    } 

    public function index(){
        $data = array();
        $search_term = $this->input->post('search');

        if($query = $this->model_home->car_search())
        {
            $data['car'] = $query;
        }
       $this->load->view('search_results', $data);
    }
}
```

Here is my model

```
public function car_search($search_term='default')
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->like('car_make',$search_term);
    $this->db->or_like('car_model',$search_term);
    $this->db->or_like('car_year',$search_term);
    $this->db->or_like('registration_number',$search_term);
    $this->db->or_like('engine_number',$search_term);
    $this->db->or_like('chasis_number',$search_term);
    $query = $this->db->get('cars');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

My search form

```
<?php 
     echo form_open('search');
     echo form_input(array('name'=>'search'));
     echo form_submit('search_submit','submit');
?>
```

My search result page

```
<?php 


if(isset($car)) : 
    foreach($car as $row) { 
    echo $row['car_make'];
     }                               //<-- moved this line
else : 
    echo '<h1> Not working </h1>';
endif; ?>
```

Its always outputting "Not Working"

Comment: Please use some sensible code indentation, otherwise the code is almost unreadable. I have reformatted your code. Also all the unnecessary Start and stopping of the PHP interpreter is quite annoying to the eye

Comment: How do you mean? Can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

This code is a bit of a mess, if you tidy it up you will see the error

Your code without all the `<?php` and `?>`

```
<?php 
    $count = 1; 
    if(isset($car)) : 
        foreach($car as $row) { 
            $count++;
        }
        echo $row['car_make']
    else : 
        echo '<h1> Not working </h1>';
    endif; 
?>
```

So you  should see the `}` in the wrong place ending the foreach loop, quite easily now, so change it to

```
<?php 

    $count = 1; 
    if(isset($car)) : 
        foreach($car as $row) { 
            $count++;
            echo $row['car_make'];
         }                               //<-- moved this line
    else : 
        echo '<h1> Not working </h1>';
    endif; 
?>
```

As you are getting the `Not Working` message I have to assume there is a problem with your querying of the database.

Probably as you are not passing the search term into the `car_search` method call. So try passing the paramter you get from the POSTed data.

```
public function index(){
    $data = array();

    if($query = $this->model_home->car_search($this->input->post('search'))) {
        $data['car'] = $query;
    }
   $this->load->view('search_results', $data);
}
```

You should also look at the default value used in the `car_search` method as the string `'default'` will almost definitely cause the query to return no results.

Comment: Thanks. I intend cleaning up the code.
But tried yours it had a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' ` on line 7

Please if the problem is from my querying any idea how I can fix that??

Comment: Semicolon after `$count++;`.

Comment: See additional answer regarding the database query

Comment: Thanks. I tried out your suggestions.. Still not outputting any results.